# Partition of a 6 or more element integer set. Combinatorial lemma

Tags: combinatorics

> Let $S=\{n_1, n_2, \ldots, n_k\}$ be a set of distinct integers such that $k\geq 6$. Suppose that $A$ and $B$ form a partition of $S$. Prove that there is an $m\in A$ and an $n\in B$ such that $|m-n|\geq 3$.

This is a combinatorial lemma I found myself using while proving the irreducibility of a family of integer polynomials. I can see that it's true intuitively, but I'm having difficulty formalizing the argument. I can most likely attack this by case-analysis and induction, but I'm hoping there's a sleeker approach.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume without loss of generality that $n_1<n_2<\cdots<n_k$ and that $n_1\in A$. For each $n_i$ with $i\ge4$, there are at least two distinct integers between $n_1$ and $n_i$, so for $i\ge4$, it is the case that $n_i\ge n_1+3$. If $n_j\in B$ for any $j\ge4$, let $m=n_1$ and $n=n_j$, and the conclusion of the theorem is true. If not, then $B\subseteq \{n_2,n_3\}$, and $B$ is nonempty (from the definition of a partition). In this case, let $m=n_6$ and let $n$ be any element of $B$. Then $n<m$, and both $n_4$ and $n_5$ are strictly between $n$ and $m$, and therefore the conclusion of the theorem is again true.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an informal argument that should be easy to flesh out formally. Take the indexing so that $n_1 < n_2 < \cdots < n_k$. Without loss of generality, $n_k \in A$. If $\min B$ is far away from $n_k$, you win. Otherwise, $n_1 \in A$ and $\min B$ is large, so you win that way.